# Using map on an array with sprintf

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
my @some_range = (6..10);
my @some_range_new = map(sprintf("I%03d ", $_), \@some_range);

say join(' ', @some_range_new)
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
I006 I007 I008 I009 I010
```

but instead I get:

```
275738152
```

Why?

**Note:** I know that I can do `my @some_range_new = ("I006".."I010")`, but I am trying to learn to use map in combination with `sprintf`

Comment: You iterate through a single scalar value (because you passed an array ref to the map function). Consequently, the program prints a scalar value (the memory address holding an array ref).

Comment: There is no way your code can produce that output. It should print the address of the `@some_range` array variable (in decimal) surrounded by `I` and a space. Whatever you get it *must* start with `I` as it is in the `sprintf` format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use a reference to `@some_range` in your map statement. I'm not sure why you thought that would work.

The correct way is

```
map sprintf("I%03d", $_), @some_range;
```

In short, just remove the backslash and your code will work.

The reason it fails is that `\@some_range` will be interpreted as a number by `%d`. When an array reference is interpreted as a number, it evaluates to the address of the referenced array. For example:

```
$ perl -lwe '@a=1..10; $x = \@a; print $x; printf "I%03d", $x'
ARRAY(0x468c18)
I4623384
```

Comment: Thanks! The examples in the documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html seem to be using references, e.g.  the first example reads: `@chars = map(chr, @numbers);`

Comment: @user815423426 There are no references there.

Comment: Gosh. I was totally mistaken. Thanks again

Comment: Won't be interpreted as a string which in turn will be interpreted as number (cause that would warn and give the number zero), it'll be interpreted as a number.